# Kotlin/JS package is empty

Tags: kotlin, npm, npm-publish, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

In the following project:
https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/AnkiMarkdown

When I push a package to NPM, it seems empty. No binary code. I do export a single class:
https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/AnkiMarkdown/blob/master/src/jsMain/kotlin/AnkiConnectorJs.kt

In the build/packages/js I have all the files I need, they are just not included in the final package.

[image]